# Laravel: How to load session variables for 'remembered' user session (LoginController is Bypassed)

Tags: php, laravel

I have built an application in Laravel 7.0 and when a user logs in, I drop some application wide variables in to session variables using by adding this to the LoginController:

```
protected function authenticated ($user)
{
    Session::put('notifications', auth()->user()->unreadNotifications);
}
```

If have verified the issue by logging out when this occurs and logging back in solves the problem (because the session variables are created as expected).

Unfortunately it seems that when a user returns to the site and it 'remembers' their previous session, the LoginController is bypassed and the session variables aren't loaded.  Does anyone know if this type of login fires an event I can regenerate the session variables in?  Or a more elegant way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Login` event, `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login`, that is fired and you can check the guard method `viaRemember` to see if they were authenticated via the remember me cookie.

You can listen for this `Login` event instead of using that `authenticated` method and you will cover both cases.

Comment: Thanks @lagbox this is the "route" I went in the end  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

$messages= [

```
        'username.min' => 'A User Name must be greater then 4 alphabets',
        'password.min' => 'A Password must be greater then 8 alphabets',
        'username.required' => 'A User Name is required',
        'password.required'  => 'A Password is required',
    ];
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255',
    ],$messages);

    if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->remember))
    {
        return back()->with('status','Invalid Credentials');
    }
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Comment: Through this method you can also remember the login token by passing it to the attempt function.